# What would make doing stuff with young children easier?

Tags: toddler, money

I think us families get ripped off when we go out and do things so I want to ask any mums and dads out there if they would join a club which gave them exclusive discounts to things to do, classes, eating out, party planning. My question is would it appeal to anyone and would they pay? It's a not for profit idea so it's really about community and families doing more.

Any ideas or suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about surveying interests, not addressing a parenting topic.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking into your local museums and municipal recreation departments. Many have programs designed for children and families that are free or low cost. MacaroniKid.com and RedTricycle.com both have a weekly digest that details regional weekend events. Meetup.com has a ton of groups devoted to family outings. Once you start finding these events, you'll start seeing them everywhere. I will say, though, that summer activities are far more plentiful than winter. Good luck!